# Vuetify : Overwrite theme colors

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to overwrite some classes.

**src/plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework"

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        primary: "#4BB7E8",
        info: "#769BD0",
        success: "#9B83BC",
        warning: "#82C341",
        error: "#53BD6D",
        default: "#30B795"
    }
})
```

and tried

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="blue lighten-5">
    <p class="success">menu goes here</p>
    <p class="info">menu goes here</p>
    <p class="primary">menu goes here</p>
    <p class="danger">menu goes here</p>
    <p class="warning">menu goes here</p>
    <p class="default">menu goes here</p>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

**Result**

> It's clearly not working because it seems to use default colors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: "#4BB7E8",
          info: "#769BD0",
          success: "#9B83BC",
          warning: "#82C341",
          error: "#53BD6D",
          default: "#30B795"
        }
      }
    }
})
```

[ https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#javascript-color-pack ]